# Implement "search as I move the map" using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to implement Airbnb's "Search as I move the map" using Leaflet. On the one hand, if a user pans the map I want to load data associated with that portion of the map, on the other hand, I don't want to make unnecessary requests (e.g. making a request every time the user slightly changes the map).

I see Leaflet provides a `moveend` event which is ["Fired when the center of the map stops changing"](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-event) but doesn't have any new location associated to it that I can use to make a new request. Also, it's probably fired too many times for this use case.

Which events should I listen to? How should I implement "search as I move the map"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `map.getCenter()` or some of its friends (eg `map.getBounds()`) from within the `moveend` event to find out where the map was panned to.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there any way to reduce the number of repeated events, you think?

Comment: Nothing built-in, you would need to debounce the events in your code.